# What would happen, gravitationally, to ships passing by each other at high speeds vs high accelerations?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, acceleration, relativity

Consider this scenario: Two identical space ships, the SS Observer and the SS Accelerator.

In **scenario A**, the SS Accelerator is accelerated up to near C, stops accelerating, then flies past the SS Observer at a minimum distance of 10m.

In **scenario B**, the SS Accelerator is accelerated up to near C at 1 million gees and continues this acceleration as it passes the SS Observer at a minimum distance of 10m.

In **scenario C**, the SS Accelerator is accelerated up to near C, reverses its acceleration, then passes the SS Observer at a minimum distance of 10m while decelerating at 1 million gees.

**The questions** are:

1. What happens to both the SS Observer and the SS Accelerator as they pass each other?
2. Are there significant differences in the interactions between the ships in the different scenarios? In other words, does the acceleration affect the gravitational interaction between the ships?

Comment: Is your question, in essence, *"is proper acceleration a source for spacetime curvature?"*?

Comment: Well that's part of it, but I'd like to understand it a little better than "yes" or "no".

Comment: Just part (2) would make a much better question.

Comment: @DilithiumMatrix Your poignant critique is duly noted.